# Botched double migration?

Tags: support, specific-question, migration

[This hilarious but serious question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7224/detecting-a-given-face-in-a-database-of-facial-images) was somehow moved to two sites:

- [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5984/justin-bieber-detector) (wtf?)
- [Statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7224/detecting-a-given-face-in-a-database-of-facial-images)

both of which aren't good picks in my opinion — this should stay on SO. But my main issue here is that the question somehow ended up on two sites. Why?

Comment: now I'm intrigued!

Comment: Sorry about the double retag, didn't notice your rollback until I've deleted that tag (and I don't see a way to roll back here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because I fat-fingered the migration on the first attempt.

I had already chosen the Statistics site in the migration window dropdown, and was confirming the site name with one of the Statistics mods, using Chat.  I guess the combo reset itself to the first entry in the list (Android) when I switched focus.

Oops.

The Statistics.SE mod wanted the question, and it had already been closed by the SO community.  It's too bad SO didn't want it; I thought it was a genuinely good question (albeit having a quirky title).

Comment: Weird. Why would SO close this one? Anyway, it seems to have found a good home on stats

Answer (score 0):

For the record, double migrations aren't possible any more, except through diamond mod intervention. (or mistakes, heh)